# WiX - The UpgradeCode under Product element is not found in registries after installation

Tags: wix

I have in my wxs file the following definition of Product (some real guid as my upgrade code):

```
<Product Id="*" Name="MyProductName" Language="1033" Codepage='1252'
           Version="1.2.3.4" Manufacturer="MyManufacturer" UpgradeCode="MY-GUID">
```

The installer msi then is added to the bundle and when I successfully install the final setup executable, then I am not able to search and find the upgrade code MY-GUID in the Windows Registry. I've read somewhere that the in the registry there should be a key with MY-GUID added under

`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UpgradeCodes\`

however, I cannot find it, not even in the whole registry. Same thing I noticed when I installed one of our legacy products with Install Shield installer. In the ISM file I can see SOME-GUID as an upgrade code

`<row><td>UpgradeCode</td><td>{SOME-GUID}</td><td/></row>`

but again after installing the product Windows Registry has no sign of SOME-GUID.

Can anyone explain what am I missing and how I can search then by upgrade code that an associated product with that upgrade code has been already installed on the machine?

Comment: [MsiEnumRelatedProducts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/msi/nf-msi-msienumrelatedproductsa) fits your bill, but I assume you'll want to find out from your WiX installer? Or what exactly is your usecase?
Also I believe I read somewhere that the upgrade codes are stored in the registry in an obfuscated form because the format is considered internal.

Comment: For one of our legacy products I migrated from the InstallShield based installer to WiX based, and I changed the upgrade code to be a new one, since we were doing a major upgrade overall for that product. Now when a new WiX based installer is being run I want to detect if an older version (one installed with InstallShield) of the product is installed and ask the user to uninstall it first before installing the new version. I know what was the upgrade code used in the InstallShield version, so I wanted to use that one to search in the registry for the installed product.

Comment: You don't need to change the upgrade code for a major upgrade, only the product code. The upgrade code you should keep the same, unless it specifically breaks your upgrade.
I suspect but haven't tried that if you want to change your upgrade code anyway, specifying the old upgrade code in an additional [`Upgrade`](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/xsd/wix/upgrade/) may work without requiring a registry search. The schema at least admits an unbounded number of `Upgrade` elements in a `Product`.

Comment: I wish it worked. That would be just perfect solution for me. I just added <Upgrade Id="OLD_INSTALLSHIELD_GUID_UPGRADE_CODE" /> with the upgrade code used for the old legacy product installer built with InstallShield, and when I tried to install the new WiX installer to upgrade the already installed old legacy product, it just installed the new one next to it. So the new one didn't uninstall the old one based on the Upgrade child element I introduced.

Comment: In the installer log for the msi including both upgrade codes, does the WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED property happen to include your old product code if and only if the old one is installed?

Comment: Looks like it worked. I need to run some more tests and will update after. Thank you.